# If sun-rays also contain any X-rays why we can't see the inner organs of the human body through these rays?

Tags: x-ray, sun-rays

Nobody has been able to find an answer how anybody may be able to see the inner organs of the human body as Natalya Demkina is able to see. In this context, I want to mention that the same way as we are able to see things in the light of an electric lamp or the sun-rays even though our eyes don't emit the visible band of the electromagnetic rays may it not be possible for her to see the inner organs of other people because the sun-rays contain X-rays also. According to me, it is wrong to say that since human eyes can't emit X-rays she may not be able to see the inner organs of other persons the same way as we are able to see everything even though our eyes don't emit the visible band of the electromagnetic waves. I want to know whether it may be possible that her brain's circuitry may be allowing her to see the inner organs through the X-ray band of the sun-rays unlike the rest of us or not. The chances of her having some special brain-circuitry of this type can't be ruled out according to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about the abilities of a Russian psychic, and only tangentially related to astronomy.

Comment: I agree that this question is not related to astronomy. But  AtmosphericPrisonEscape has answered my question very well. I express my thanks to AtmosphericPrisonEscape. Since I got an answer I don't mind if it is removed from the astronomy segment of stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

X-Rays from the sun don't reach the Earth's surface, as our atmosphere is opaque to this kind of electromagnetic radiation.
This is why X-Ray observatories like the [Chandra telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandra_X-ray_Observatory) have to be placed in space. Thus it is excluded, that anybody having an ability to see X-Rays would see people's inner organs.

The other issue is that in general, human physiology doesn't allow to see electromagnetic radiation this energetic. Our abilities to see high-energetic radiation ends at the violet colour, which is where UV radiation has it's name from. X-Rays are even more energetic than UV.